# How to drag an image(png) in both directions on touch in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have used linear layout in android that has an image of semicircle type. I have to drag that image in both directions depending upon the intensity of the flick by the user.

Any Idea?

Comment: i am able to move images but not able to drag

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: LinearLayout  spinner = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.anim_example);
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.spinner);
     int w = bmp.getWidth();
     int h = bmp.getHeight();
     // Setting post rotate to 90
     Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
     mtx.postRotate(90);
     // Rotating Bitmap
     Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
     BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

     spinner.setBackgroundDrawable(bmd);

Answer (score 0):

Since you use bitmaps, you could simply

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
```

then just get the position with some touch event and thats it

Viewflipper is meant for XML layouts to be switched in and out